# HttpSessionAttributeListener Confusion

Tags: servlets

I am reading about HttpSessionAttributeListener and here is a small example i made.
I have one doubt though. The code is given below

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    doPost(request,response);
  }

  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    Dog d = new Dog();
    d.setName("Peter");
    session.setAttribute("test", d);
    /*Dog d1 = new Dog();
    d1.setName("Adam");
    */
    d.setName("Adam");
    session.setAttribute("test",d);
  }

}
```

Here is my Listener class

```
public class MyAttributeListener implements HttpSessionAttributeListener {
  @Override
  public void attributeAdded(HttpSessionBindingEvent httpSessionBindingEvent) {
    System.out.println("Attribute Added");
    String attributeName = httpSessionBindingEvent.getName();
    Dog attributeValue = (Dog) httpSessionBindingEvent.getValue();
    System.out.println("Attribute Added:" + attributeName + ":" + attributeValue.getName());

  }

  @Override
  public void attributeRemoved(HttpSessionBindingEvent httpSessionBindingEvent) {
    String attributeName = httpSessionBindingEvent.getName();
    String attributeValue = (String) httpSessionBindingEvent.getValue();
    System.out.println("Attribute removed:" + attributeName + ":" + attributeValue);


  }

  @Override
  public void attributeReplaced(HttpSessionBindingEvent httpSessionBindingEvent) {
    String attributeName = httpSessionBindingEvent.getName();
    Dog attributeValue = (Dog) httpSessionBindingEvent.getValue();
    System.out.println("Attribute replaced:" + attributeName + ":" + attributeValue.getName());

  }
}
```

Here is my model

```
public class Dog  {
  private String name ;

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

The confusion is when i run this program, the listener calls the attribute added and
replaced perfectly. When i uncomment the code in my servlet and comment

```
d.setName("Adam")
```

The attribute replaced does get called. But the value of name remains Peter only. Why
is that? What's the reason? Another question when do we use HttpSessionAttributeListener
and HttpSessionListener in particular. Any practical usages?

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 1):

Because [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionBindingEvent.html#getValue%28%29) says:

> Returns the value of the attribute that has been added, removed or
>   replaced. If the attribute was added (or bound), this is the value of
>   the attribute. If the attribute was removed (or unbound), this is the
>   value of the removed attribute. If the attribute was replaced, this is
>   the old value of the attribute.

In the first case, the old value and the new value are the same, so you see the new dog name.

HttpSessionListener is used to be aware of session creation and destruction. HttpSessionAttributeListener  is used to be aware of new, removed and replaced attributes in the session. They're very different.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nizet. I got your point that when the new value is replaced we get the old value of the attribute as per the javadoc. Thanks a ton :)